# Google App Engine - This app has no instances deployed

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask, app.yaml

App Instances:

[image]

App Versions:

[image: App Versions Screenshot]

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /my_uri
  script: path.to.my.script.script.app
```

I created a Python Flask app with Google App Engine. I initially ran into some issues, so I re-deployed the app. This created a new version. After doing so, I deleted the previously existing version which had one instance deployed. The currently deployed version has no instances deployed, as you can see in the image at the link above.

When I submit a request to my-app-ID.appspot.com/my_uri, I get a 404 error:

> Error: Not Found
>
> The requested URL /my_uri was not found on this server.

I believe this is related to my app not having an instance deployed. Is that correct? If so, how would I remedy this?

If not, what could be causing the 404 issue?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What do you your app logs say? https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Comment: There's a lot - What specifically should I be looking for? A few specific items include:
"No handlers matched this URL.", 
"instanceIndex: -1"

Comment: The logs for the request(s) you'd expect from `gcloud app browse`. Also - how does your app's versions page looks like? https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions. And how does you `app.yaml` looks like?

Comment: I posted a screenshot of my versions and I included my app.yaml. Thank you for your help.

Comment: From your `app.yaml` the app would only know how to reply to requests for `/my_uri` (the only pattern with a script). Try to replace that with `/.*` or add a handler  for `/` (which is, I suspect, what `gcloud app browse` requests) - the request logs should show exactly the path for each request.

Comment: The version page shows the version is serving, so GAE will start an instance automatically when a request matches one of the `app.yaml` handler patterns with a script configured.

Comment: Yes -- `/my_uri` is the only request I am making for now. I tried replacing `/my_uri` with something like `/.*` and `/` to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

As your error message indicates `gcloud app browse` makes a request for the `/` url to your app.

From [Request handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-handled#Python_Requests):

> When App Engine receives a web request for your application, it calls
>   the handler script that corresponds to the URL, as described in the
>   application's `[app.yaml][2]` configuration file . The Python 2.7
>   runtime supports the [WSGI standard](http://www.wsgi.org/) and the [CGI standard](http://www.w3.org/CGI/) for
>   backwards compatibility. WSGI is preferred, and some features of
>   Python 2.7 do not work without it. The configuration of your
>   application's [script handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#handlers_element) determines whether a request is
>   handled using WSGI or CGI.

But your `app.yaml` file does not contain a handler with a matching url pattern (as `/` doesn't match `/my_uri`), so GAE doesn't know which app script to launch for that request, so it'll return 404.

So the first thing you have to do is to add in `app.yaml` a handler with a url pattern that matches a `/` request.

You may want to go through the  [Getting Started with Flask on App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/python-standard-env) guide. In there the recommended handler would be:

> ```
> handlers:
> - url: /.*
>   script: main.app
> ```

The above alone won't necessarily make your app work, there's plenty of other things that can go wrong. You should get familiar with the app's log viewer as that's essential for debugging your app. See [Understanding request log fields](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/#understanding_request_log_fields)

But before you even go to deployment on GAE, learn how to run and test your app locally. See [Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-local-server)

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, Dan. I edited my post to be more clear.  I am attempting a request to `/my_uri`, and GAE tells me that the URL `/my_uri` doesn't exist.

Comment: OK. But this time an instance should be started by your request, even if it fails in the end. Do you have a matching pattern for `/my_uri` in the `app` definition from your `path.to.my.script.script.py` script?